# How to get data from a file in fluentd logger

Tags: json, logging, fluentd

I have a python code running as a service in the background. It generates a `data.json` file which contains a json data, something like below

```
{
   "Type":"Data"
   "Name":"XYZ"
   "Level":32
}
```

This data is updated every 120s. So after every 120s, there are new values for the tags in `data.json`. I want this information to read by input plugin of fluentd logger but not sure which plugin to use here. I can not use `tail` as I am not tailing anything into this file. Can anyone please suggest or refer me to good links/tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution for your use case is to use the [exec plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_exec) .
You can use this plugin to write a script that will print the relevant keys to stdout and be collected by fluentd. Does that work for you?

Example -

```
<source>
  @type exec
  command node json_parser.js
  run_interval 120s
</source>
```

You can then write the entire logic for parsing your json inside `json_parser.js`, and print the values you want ingested by fluentd using `console.log` statements.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can you give an example please.

Comment: Sure, I added an example to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the example. I thought you were trying to say about linux script but I didnt get this `.js`. Is this also a linux script or you are trying to say that I should write my own input plugin. Sorry but I am newbie in this. Can you explain a bit more about `node json_parser.js`. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are correct that exex runs a linux script, but node is actually a linux script that can take a node.js file as an argument. It just seemed like the easiest way to manipulate json files but you can use python, bash, ruby or whatever language you are comfortable with.

Comment: You mean to say I need to create a linux script which will print the values inside the json file and it will automatically be used in fluentd. I am getting confused as to how the fluentd will get json data if I print it using a script. Can you add a bit of a code with explanation. Thankyou very much